# Jdbc check type compatiblity

Tags: sql, database, types, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Is there some way to check beforehand if a java type is compatible with a `sql.Types`?

I could type out all the stuff like:

`if (BIGINT||TINYINT) try BigInteger.parse(myvalue)` and 
`if (TIME||DATE||TIMESTAMP) try new Date(Long.parse(myvalue))`

This creates tonnes of code. Is their some generic way of prechecking?

EDIT: I'm talking about inserts, so I want to do some prechecking, to avoid sql exceptions while inserting

Comment: Why not use `ResultSet#getObject()` and/or `PreparedStatement#setObject()`? Or, better, an ORM like Hibernate, JPA and like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JDBC, just use [ResultSet.getObject()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29). It will return what type is appropriate (let the JDBC driver do the heavy lifting).

Only use the typed getters, eg [getInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29), when you know what you're expecting from the column.

Comment: I'm talking about inserts, so I want to do some prechecking, to avoid sql exceptions while inserting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question. Do you mean `instanceof`?

```
ie. if (myObject instanceof java.sql.Types) {
        ...
    }
```